# Change parent size with this same ratio and resize all children with this same positions and ratio using css/js

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I have parent element, parent element should be responsive and should change size to fit to screen with this same ratio aspect, like on screen below (grey - screen, red - parent element)

[image: wanted div resolutions]

This element can have some childrens with random size (but always less than parent) on random positions.

How to make resizable div with this same aspect ratio having children inside and most important how to resize childrens depend on parent with this ratio and keep childrens positions on this same places using css/js?

[image]

Childrens positions are absolute.

Comment: Instead of worrying about actual sizes, I'd think more about percentages. Child element 1 is 100 wide, which is 10% of the parent. 400 height which is  20% of the parent. It's position witihn the parent should be x% across and down. If you do things that way, it'll naturally scale very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS that helps here is aspect-ratio. Specifically, if the max-aspect-ratio is 1/2 then the width and height can be set in terms of vw and if not then in terms of vh.

Positions and sizes of the child elements can be set as %s of the parent so they remain correct whatever the changes in size.

Here's an example with just one child, but easily expanded to accommodate more.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

#parent {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50vw - 25vh);
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-width: 1vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#child1 {
  width: 10%;
  height: 20%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/2) {
  #parent {
    height: 200vw;
    width: 100vw;
    top: calc(50vh - 100vw);
    left: 0px;    
  }
  .child {
    border-width: 1vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1" class="child"></div>
</div>
```